# How to add TCP/IP and named pipe in SQL connection string?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

how to add tcp/ip and named pipe in odbc  sql server connection string. I am using visual foxpro.

any helps ?

Comment: You can specify `Network=dbmssocn` or `Network=dbnmpntw` for TCP/IP or Named Pipes respectively.

Comment: Does it give more perfomance ?